# Writing Spec for singleton class RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, singleton

I have some method in singleton class need to write rspec on Ruby on Rails.
Here is sample class

```
class Logger
  class << self
    def log(event, msg)
      data = Helper.send(event, msg)
      PublishJob.perform(data)
    end
  end
end
```

How to write a test method called Helper.send... and Run a job?

Thank all

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: You might want to see this gem, it will help you test your background job.
https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq

Answer (score 0):

You can test that the `Logger` calls `Helper` and `PublishJob` by stubbing the methods of the class:

```
describe Logger do
  let(:event) { double("Event") }
  let(:msg) { double("Message") }
  let(:data) { double("Data") }

  before do
    allow(Helper).to receive(:send).and_return(data)
    allow(PublishJob).to receive(:perform)
  end

  before { Logger.log(event, msg) }

  it "sends a message and performs a job" do
    expect(Helper).to have_received(:send).with(event, msg)
    expect(PublishJob).to have_received(:perform).with(data)
  end
end
```

And the details of performing the job, can be tested in the spec file for the job itself.